# (415) Unsupported Media Type while posting envelopes in DocuSign

Tags: vb.net, docusignapi, webrequest

I am getting this error while trying to post an envelope:

> (415) Unsupported Media Type

Here is my code:

```
Dim httpWebRequest =     DirectCast(WebRequest.Create("https://demo.docusign.net/restapi/v2/accounts/1005732/envelopes"), HttpWebRequest)

httpWebRequest.ContentType = "text/json"
httpWebRequest.Method = "POST"
httpWebRequest.Accept = "text/json"
httpWebRequest.MediaType = "text/json"

httpWebRequest.Headers.Add("X-DocuSign-Authentication", "{""Username"": ""myuser"",""Password"": ""mypassword"",""IntegratorKey"": ""mykey""}")

Using streamWriter = New StreamWriter(httpWebRequest.GetRequestStream())
Dim json As String = "{""status"": ""sent"",""emailBlurb"": ""Test Email Body"",""emailSubject"": ""Test Email Subject"",""documents"": [{""name"":   ""C:\Ant.htm"",""documentId"": ""1"",""order"": ""1""}],""recipients"":    {""signers"": [{""email"": ""eladrozman@gmail.com"",""name"":    ""Elad"",""recipientId"": ""1"",""tabs"": {""signHereTabs"": [{""xPosition"": ""100"",""yPosition"": ""100"",""documentId"": ""1"",""pageNumber"": ""1""}]}}]}}"

streamWriter.Write(json)
End Using

Dim httpResponse = DirectCast(httpWebRequest.GetResponse(), HttpWebResponse)
```

Comment: What language is this?  [tag:vb.net]?  [tag:VBA]? [tag:vbscript]? ...?

Comment: @Degustaf `WebRequest.Create` is part of the .NET framework, so this is `vb.net` which was declined by you in my edit suggestion (Thank you sir, for my first declined edit).

Comment: @FrankerZ Apologies.  The different dialects of VB look very similar.  I didn't want it tagged with the wrong language, and I am not familiar with `WebRequest`

Comment: Where are you actually attaching your document in your request? Can you post your REST Request? instead of code?

Answer (score 0):

There's no such media type as `text/json`.  You need to use `application/json` for the Content-Type and other headers.